# How to remove duplicate row in array of hashes on Ruby on rails

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I am using Ruby 2.6 in my application.

I want to remove the duplicate element in array of hashes. Here is my input

```
array_of_hashes = [
{"Date"=> "2019-05-6", "ID" => 100, "Rate" => 10, "Count" => 1},
{"Date"=> "2019-05-6", "ID" => 100, "Rate" => nil, "Count" => 0},
{"Date"=> "2019-05-6", "ID" => 101, "Rate" => 25, "Count" => 3},
{"Date"=> "2019-05-6", "ID" => 102, "Rate" => nil, "Count" => 0},
{"Date"=> "2019-05-6", "ID" => 102, "Rate" => 35, "Count" => 0},
{"Date"=> "2019-05-6", "ID" => 103, "Rate" => 20, "Count" => 6}
]
```

I am creating key, value pair from the hash for the need of my application.

```
result = array_of_hashes.map { |row| [[row['ID'], row['Date'], row] }.to_h
```

If there are two records with same "ID" and "Date" values in a hash, I want to rows the row where "Rate" != 0 where input records order might shuffle. Here is my Actual and Expected result.

Actual Result:

```
 {[100, "2019-05-6"]=>{"Date"=>"2019-05-6", "ID"=>100, "Rate"=>nil, "Count"=>0},
 [101, "2019-05-6"]=>{"Date"=>"2019-05-6", "ID"=>101, "Rate"=>25, "Count"=>3},
 [102, "2019-05-6"]=>{"Date"=>"2019-05-6", "ID"=>102, "Rate"=>35, "Count"=>0},
 [103, "2019-05-6"]=>{"Date"=>"2019-05-6", "ID"=>103, "Rate"=>20, "Count"=>6}}
```

Expected result:

```
 {[100, "2019-05-6"]=>{"Date"=>"2019-05-6", "ID"=>100, "Rate"=>10, "Count"=>1}, 
 [101, "2019-05-6"]=>{"Date"=>"2019-05-6", "ID"=>101, "Rate"=>25, "Count"=>3},
 [102, "2019-05-6"]=>{"Date"=>"2019-05-6", "ID"=>102, "Rate"=>35, "Count"=>0},
 [103, "2019-05-6"]=>{"Date"=>"2019-05-6", "ID"=>103, "Rate"=>20, "Count"=>6}}
```

How can I get the above expected result?

Comment: 1. Can the "expected result" contain a value (hash) for which `Rate = nil`? 2. Can `array_of_hashes` contain two elements having the same values for `"ID"` and `"Date"` and neither has a `nil` value for `"Rate"`? If "yes", which should be selected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another group by option

```
array_of_hashes.group_by {|h| h.values_at("ID","Date")}.transform_values do |v|   
  v.find {|r| r["Rate"]}
end

#=> {[100, "2019-05-6"]=>{"Date"=>"2019-05-6", "ID"=>100, "Rate"=>10, "Count"=>1}, 
#    [101, "2019-05-6"]=>{"Date"=>"2019-05-6", "ID"=>101, "Rate"=>25, "Count"=>3}, 
#    [102, "2019-05-6"]=>{"Date"=>"2019-05-6", "ID"=>102, "Rate"=>35, "Count"=>0}, 
#    [103, "2019-05-6"]=>{"Date"=>"2019-05-6", "ID"=>103, "Rate"=>20, "Count"=>6}}
```

group by id and date then transform the `Hash` values to the first `Hash` where "Rate" is not `nil`.

If multiple values are acceptable then `find_all` or `select` could be substituted for `find`.

If you want the original structure maintained just add `values` to the end.

Comment: ...or `!r["Rate"].nil?` to read better (?) and not worry about the value of `"Rate"` being `false` (however unlikely that may be).

Comment: @CarySwoveland Really you think that reads better? I would prefer `v.lazy.reject {|r| r["Rate"].nil? }.first` over that and to the same effect as `find` first non `nil` rate hash returned without regard for other hashes in the group.

Comment: "Reads better" because when I see `{|r| r["Rate"]}` the question, "what about `false`?" immediately comes to mind and requires processing. My `"(?)"` reflects the need for `!`. What I'd really like is `{|r| r["Rate"].non_nil? }`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland you could go with something super ugly like `r unless r['Rate'].nil?`

Answer (score 2):

We can construct the desired hash by making a single pass through `array_of_hashes`.

```
array_of_hashes.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
  k = [g['ID'], g['Date']]
  h.update(k=>g) unless h.key?(k) && h[k]['Rate'] != nil
end
  #=> {[100, "2019-05-6"]=>{"Date"=>"2019-05-6", "ID"=>100, "Rate"=>10, "Count"=>1},
  #    [101, "2019-05-6"]=>{"Date"=>"2019-05-6", "ID"=>101, "Rate"=>25, "Count"=>3},
  #    [102, "2019-05-6"]=>{"Date"=>"2019-05-6", "ID"=>102, "Rate"=>35, "Count"=>0},
  #    [103, "2019-05-6"]=>{"Date"=>"2019-05-6", "ID"=>103, "Rate"=>20, "Count"=>6}}
```

This assumes that if two elements of `array_of_hashes` match on the values of `'ID'` and `'Date'`, and neither has a value of `nil` for `'Rate'`, the first of the two hashes is retained. If the latter of the two should be retained change the second line of the method to:

```
h.update(k=>g) unless h.key?(k) && g['Rate'].nil?
```

Comment: for the first solution you could go with `if h.dig(k,'Rate').nil?` it is fail fast so the result would be the same.

Comment: @engineersmnky, I've not seen that before. Clever!

Answer (score 1):

Use group_by and filter nil rates from the values.

```
array_of_hashes
  .group_by { |h| [h["ID"], h["Date"]] }
  .map { |key, values| [key, values.reject { |row| row["Rate"].nil? }.last] }
  .to_h
```

Comment: You don't want the rows where rate is nil I assume?

Comment: Yes. I want the rows where rate is not nil and input records are in shuffled every-time

Comment: Why .last is needed here?

Comment: It is if we want the result you specified where only one row is returned. If you want potentially several rows per ID-Date tuple you can just simply drop the .last.